# Unused global options warning

Tags: warnings

I get a warning:

> Unused global option(s):
>   [11pt,a4paper]

The code that I've been using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,polish,thesis]{dcsbook}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

I've checked forums and seems like 11pt and a4paper are both valid options.
How do I fix it?

@Edit The next message is

```
(thesis-template-latex.aux) (C:\...\Miktex 2.9\tex\latex\lm\t1lmr.fd")
```

Content of thesis-template-latex.aux:

```
\relax 
\catcode `"\active 
\select@language{polish}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{polish}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{polish}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{polish}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Wst\IeC {\k e}p}{3}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Cel i zakres pracy}{3}}
\citation{ruby1}
\citation{rails1}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}U\IeC {\.z}yte narz\IeC {\k e}dzia}{5}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}Ruby}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}Ruby on Rails}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.2.1}Model-View-Controller}{6}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2.1}{\ignorespaces Schematyczna reprezentacja wzorca model-view-controller.\relax }}{7}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.3}Bootstrap}{7}}
\citation{test1}
\citation{ruby3}
\citation{rails4}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Test Driven Development}{9}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {4}Deployment aplikacji}{13}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {5}Opis relacji w bazie danych}{15}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {5.1}{\ignorespaces Schemat relacji w bazie danych\relax }}{16}}
\bibcite{ruby1}{1}
\bibcite{ruby2}{2}
\bibcite{ruby3}{3}
\bibcite{rails1}{4}
\bibcite{rails2}{5}
\bibcite{rails3}{6}
\bibcite{rails4}{7}
\bibcite{test1}{8}
\bibcite{automa1}{9}
\bibcite{automa2}{10}
\bibcite{automa3}{11}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{Bibliografia}{17}}
\ttl@finishall
```

Comment: this class? http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/software/latex/dcsgroup-classes.html

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Answer (score 9):

You don't say but I assume the class is

http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/software/latex/dcsgroup-classes.html

this has two `\ProcessOptions` commands which is an error and the cause of the spurious message.

To remove them would take some re-arranging of the class code to make sure that you have no `\RequirePackage` lines between `\DeclareOption` and `\ProcessOptions`.

On the other hand as far as I can see it is working as intended except for the second `\ProcessOptions` confusing LaTeX internals about which options have been handled so just ignoring the error is safe enough, although you should report to the class author.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I was hoping there might be an easy answer, but since I am not an expert in latex stuff, I will just let him know about the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

(Is the above quote the complete error message?  Look at you log file.  It should tell you exactly, which file was complaining.)

I don't know the `dcsbook`-class, you are using, but if you get that error message, it seems, as if those options aren't really defined in that class.

Try to replace `dcsbook` by normal `book` or the somewhat european brother `scrbook` and the error message will disappear.

If you have to use `dcsbook`, than remove the options `11pt, a4paper` instead, to get rid of the error message.

But maybe, you have to give us more information at all?

Comment: You're right, there is a file name after that message. I'll edit main post and add it here.

Comment: even if you don't know a class, google can usually find it, removing 11pt,a4paper would be the wrong thing to do as it would not just get rid of the warning it would mean the thesis was no longer formatted for a4paper at 11pt.